# Get file contents from file in folder with spaces

Tags: php, file

I have an image file that I want to read with PHP:

```
$imagefile = "/Billing/Billing Client Name/WebFolder/image.png";
echo file_exists($imagefile); //Returns false;

$imagefile = "/Billing/Billing+Client+Name/WebFolder/image.png";
echo file_exists($imagefile); //Returns False;

$imagefile = "/Billing/Billing%20Client%20Name/WebFolder/image.png";
echo file_exists($imagefile); //Returns False;

$imagefile = urlencode("/Billing/Billing Client Name")."/WebFolder/image.png";
echo file_exists($imagefile); //Returns False;

//After Chaging the folder name
$imagefile = "/Billing/BillingClientName/WebFolder/image.png";
echo file_exists($imagefile); //Returns True;
```

It appears the issue is with spaces in the folder name.  Are spaces allowed in the foldernames and, if so, How do I manipulate the folder name so php can properly process the file?

Thank you.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I read that post prior to posting this one.  The post did not provide a solution.

Comment: 2 lines of code doesn't cut it here. You need to update your question with what you tried.

Comment: `echo $file_exists` are you really using `$` here? That's a function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php not a variable.

Comment: @jayBlanchard- is the issue was a duplicate then the first attempt in my code would have worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  Oops...edited the question

Comment: I'm out of options. see if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php returns anything. wish I could be of more help

Comment: I know nothing of this "first attempt" you speak of.

Comment: Jay, the first $imagefile variable in my question has the folder "as is" with spaces.

Comment: Maybe it is a lower level server issue? I can't make heads or tails of it.